# Getting an error when trying to add data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a contributor data to the database using the controller and I am getting the following error:

The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

Source Error: 
Line 195:  //@returnInventoryId AS  int OUTPUT
Line 196:
Line 197:  var recordsAffected = dbFFS.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
Line 198:  "sp_InsertOrUpdateContributor @electionId, @candidateId, @contributorId, @eligibleForRebate, @lastName, @firstName, @middleName, @fullName, @contributorTypeAbbr, @streetNo, @streetName, @unit, @city, @province, @country, @postalCode, @mailingAddress1, @mailingAddress2, @mailingAddress3, @mailingAddress4, @homePhone, @workPhone, @cellPhone, @emailAddress, @notes,  @returnInventoryId OUT  ",
Line 199:  param1, param2, param3, param4, param2, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10, param11, param12, param13, param14, param15, param16, param18, param19, param20, param21, param22, param23, param24, param25, param15, param15, pOutput);
```

The following is my code [Controller]:

```
public ActionResult Edit(ffsContributor model)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
            //0 Username | 1 Fullname | 2 User Id | 3 Login Type | 4 Election Id
            string[] UserData = ticket.UserData.Split('|');

            if (UserData[3] != "candidate")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            int candidateid = Convert.ToInt32(UserData[2]);
            int electionID = Convert.ToInt32(UserData[4]);

            model = dbFFSSave(electionID, candidateid, model);

            //check inventory request is the same with the model
            return View(model);

        }

        public ActionResult Add()
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
            //0 Username | 1 Fullname | 2 User Id | 3 Login Type | 4 Election Id
            string[] UserData = ticket.UserData.Split('|');

            if (UserData[3] != "candidate")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            int candidateid = Convert.ToInt32(UserData[2]);
            int electionID = Convert.ToInt32(UserData[4]);

            ffsContributor model = new ffsContributor
            {
                CandidateId = candidateid,
                ContributorId = 0
            };

            model.DropDownList = DbFFSGetOffices(electionID, candidateid);

            return View(model);
        }

        private Models.ffsContributor dbFFSSave(int electionId, int candidateID, Models.ffsContributor model)
        {

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@electionId", electionId);
            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@candidateId", model.CandidateId);
            //SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@contributorId", model.ContributorId);
            SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@eligibleForRebate", model.EligibleForRebate);
            SqlParameter param5 = new SqlParameter("@lastName", model.LastName);
            SqlParameter param6 = new SqlParameter("@firstName", model.FirstName);
            SqlParameter param7 = new SqlParameter("@middleName", model.MiddleName);
            SqlParameter param8 = new SqlParameter("@fullName", model.FullName);
            SqlParameter param9 = new SqlParameter("@contributorTypeAbbr", model.ContributorTypeAbbr);
            SqlParameter param10 = new SqlParameter("@streetNo", model.StreetNo);
            SqlParameter param11 = new SqlParameter("@streetName", model.StreetName);
            SqlParameter param12 = new SqlParameter("@unit", model.Unit);
            SqlParameter param13 = new SqlParameter("@streetName", model.StreetName);
            SqlParameter param14 = new SqlParameter("@city", model.City);
            SqlParameter param15 = new SqlParameter("@province", model.Province);
            SqlParameter param16 = new SqlParameter("@postalCode", model.PostalCode);
            SqlParameter param18 = new SqlParameter("@mailingAddress1", model.MailingAddress1);
            SqlParameter param19 = new SqlParameter("@mailingAddress2", model.MailingAddress2);
            SqlParameter param20 = new SqlParameter("@mailingAddress3", model.MailingAddress3);
            SqlParameter param21 = new SqlParameter("@mailingAddress4", model.MailingAddress4);
            SqlParameter param22 = new SqlParameter("@homePhone", model.HomePhone);
            SqlParameter param23 = new SqlParameter("@workPhone", model.WorkPhone);
            SqlParameter param24 = new SqlParameter("@emailAddress", model.EmailAddress);
            SqlParameter param25 = new SqlParameter("@notes", model.Notes);

            SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@contributorId", DBNull.Value);


            //if (model.ContributorId < 0)
            //{
              //  param5.Value = model.ContributorId;
            //}


            var pOutput = new SqlParameter("@returnContributorId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
            {
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
            };
            //@returnInventoryId AS  int OUTPUT

            var recordsAffected = dbFFS.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                                "sp_InsertOrUpdateContributor @electionId, @candidateId, @contributorId, @eligibleForRebate, @lastName, @firstName, @middleName, @fullName, @contributorTypeAbbr, @streetNo, @streetName, @unit, @city, @province, @country, @postalCode, @mailingAddress1, @mailingAddress2, @mailingAddress3, @mailingAddress4, @homePhone, @workPhone, @cellPhone, @emailAddress, @notes,  @returnInventoryId OUT  ",
                                param1, param2, param3, param4, param2, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10, param11, param12, param13, param14, param15, param16, param18, param19, param20, param21, param22, param23, param24, param25, param15, param15, pOutput);


            model.DropDownList = DbFFSGetOffices(electionId, candidateID);

            return model;

        }
```

My cshtml file:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ffsContributors"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ContributorId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, new { @placeholder = "FullName" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @placeholder = "EmailAddress" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkPhone, new { @placeholder = "WorkPhone" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomePhone, new { @placeholder = "HomePhone" })
   // @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CellPhone, Model.DropDownList)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What is that `dbFFS` object?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the parameter "@streetName" twice to your ExecuteSqlCommand().
Remove one of this:

```
SqlParameter param11 = new SqlParameter("@streetName", model.StreetName);
SqlParameter param13 = new SqlParameter("@streetName", model.StreetName);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlParameter param11 = new SqlParameter("@streetName", model.StreetName);
SqlParameter param13 = new SqlParameter("@streetName", model.StreetName);
```

Also, using `command.Parameters.AddWithValue()` may help make it less error-prone.

Comment: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @David, good point! I think using `command.Parameters.Add(<...>).Value = <Value>` should solve the problem.